# missing ) after argument list error with scriptmanager

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I get this error when the code below is executed.  Please help.

```
Dim sb1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb1.Append("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>")
        sb1.Append("window.open('../reports/Receipt.aspx?receiptno=" & Me.txtReceiptNo.Text.Trim & "&payorno=" & Me.txtPHospitalNo.Text.Trim & "&payorname=" & Me.txtPName.Text.Trim.Replace("'", """") & "&totalamount=" & amt & "&inwords=" & inwords & "&paytype=" & ddlPaymentType.SelectedItem.Text & "&payref=" & txtRef.Text.Trim & "&user=" & ViewState("username") & "&type=2&datecollected='" & datecollected & "'&company=" & company & "&roleid=" & ViewState("RoleId") & "&isRefund=false")
        sb1.Append("','EncounterForm','toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');")
        sb1.Append("</script>")

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "test", sb1.ToString, False)
```

Comment: Probaly some quote in the values you are replacing (like here `&type=2&datecollected='`). What is the actual output in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you include the full error message in the body of your question next time? Makes it easier to read. It took me a second to look back up and notice the title. Seems like your IDE should be able to help with syntax errors like this and highlight the line and column number where the error is.

Comment: `&datecollected='" & datecollected & "'&company="` ... see those `'` in there

Comment: I think @Lain got the point

Comment: @Lain - noticed that :p

Answer (score 0):

If I change your code a bit (since I do not have your variables) to this:

```
Dim tDummy As String = "coucou"
Dim sb1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb1.Append("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>")
sb1.Append("window.open('../reports/Receipt.aspx?receiptno=" & tDummy & "&payorno=" & tDummy & "&payorname=" & tDummy & "&totalamount=" & tDummy & "&inwords=" & tDummy & "&paytype=" & tDummy & "&payref=" & tDummy & "&user=" & tDummy & "&type=2&datecollected='" & tDummy & "'&company=" & tDummy & "&roleid=" & tDummy & "&isRefund=false")
sb1.Append("','EncounterForm','toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');")
sb1.Append("</script>")
```

I get the following - invalid - output in Javascript (`&datecollected='coucou'&`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.open('../reports/Receipt.aspx?receiptno=coucou&payorno=coucou&payorname=coucou&totalamount=coucou&inwords=coucou&paytype=coucou&payref=coucou&user=coucou&type=2&datecollected='coucou'&company=coucou&roleid=coucou&isRefund=false','EncounterForm','toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');
</script>
```

You will have to escape or remove the extra single quotes which you are using as string delimiter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.open('../reports/Receipt.aspx?receiptno=coucou&payorno=coucou&payorname=coucou&totalamount=coucou&inwords=coucou&paytype=coucou&payref=coucou&user=coucou&type=2&datecollected=coucou&company=coucou&roleid=coucou&isRefund=false','EncounterForm','toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');
</script>
```